# open hyperlink with voice input in dialog-flow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I'm newbie in Dialog-flow development. I need to open a hyperlink dynamically in fulfillment(below) of the follow-up intent, which gets triggered when user provides voice input as ‘Yes’.

```
function confirmation(agent) {
< code to open hyperlink >
}
```

I have tried *Link out suggestion* but that doesn't seem to be working.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot trigger a hyperlink for Actions.

Alternatively, you could use a rich response like a browsing carousel: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#browsing_carousel

This will allow the user to click on a card to launch to a web site.

Comment: Thnaks Leon! I want to link Google account when user gets navigated to my login page, when he says *Yes*  to give confirmation to link. We do this with Account Linking action right?

Comment: Yes, we recommend Google sign-in: https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in